# Outlook 365 Blurry Signature Images on Mobile (High DPI Issue)

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, blurry

I have scoured the internet and haven't found a solution for the blurry logo image I've inserted into my signature.

I'm using Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11629.20238) 64-bit

I have tried several different image sizes and resolution settings (96 ppi).

I have made the image the exact size it needs to be but at a higher ppi, I've tried making the image much larger and then sizing it down for Outlook but the image always shows up blurry on mobile.

I've provided screenshots below and the ZIP file with a composed message with the signature

ZIP file:
https://www.tripspark.com/resource_files/Blurry_Image.zip

Desktop - clear

[image: desktop]

Mobile - unclear

[image: mobile]

Please help!

I've also tried editing some of the properties in the html file as well:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
```